# regexp how to define expression for each symbol(include newline)?

Tags: c#, regex

I have regexp:

```
regex = "= (.*)$";
```

but it don't work if line includes some new lines. How can i improve it?

```
string input = "KEY = \"test ssss123 KEYTWO assas = \" \n test \n test test";
```

I would like to get from input this line: "\"test ssss123 KEYTWO assas = \" \n test \n test test";

Answer (score 0):

Use DOTALL modifier `(?s)` to make dot to match even newline `\n` or carriage return `\r` characters also.

```
regex = @"(?s)= (.*)$";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DOTALL` flag `(?s)` or use this regex:

```
regex = @"= ([\\s\\S]*)$";
```

`[\s\S]` will match any character including newline and will work on tool/languages such as Javascript also that do not support `DOTALL` flag.